# Format integer to minutes with new Foundation formatters?

Tags: swiftui, nsdateformatter, foundation, formatter, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying to format an integer to display it as minutes, but I can't get the syntax right and the docs are still light on this. This is what I'm trying:

```
let value: Int = 20
Text(value.formatted(.components(style: .abbreviated, fields: [.minute])))
// Compile error: Instance method 'formatted' requires the types 'Int' and 'Date.ComponentsFormatStyle.FormatInput' (aka 'Range<Date>') be equivalent
```

I'm trying to display: `20 min`. How can this be done using the [new Foundation formatters](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10109/) improvements from WWDC 2021?

I can do this the old way like this:

```
static let formatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.unitsStyle = .short
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute]
    return formatter
}()

Self.formatter.string(for: DateComponents(minute: value))
```

Comment: The syntax in your code is supposed to be applied to a `Date` related value, approximately this is what the error says.

Answer (score 0):

to format an integer you need a NumberFormatter. Or you could just do:

```
Text("\(value) min")
```

Comment: I was looking to do it with the new formatter additions to Foundation. Also this would require me to create localisations per language.

Comment: I thought your question was "I'm trying to display: 20 min. How can this be done?"